# Simple Timer/Alarm lags when using timer.tick

Tags: vb.net, timer

I made a simple timer/alarm desktop application for myself but it doesn't quite work.

I used timer.tick to check the current time from System.Now and performed a compare with a hard coded time every second. This worked fine for 1 alarm time but for multiple alarms the clock started lagging when performing multiple compares.

Is there a standard method for making timers/alarms?

I thought that having the timer.tick would be better than leaving an infinite for loop performing a compare (I'm probably completely wrong), how would you do it?

Thanks.

Comment: A timer will always lag, its tick event handler cannot run instantly the very moment the interval expires.  The more work you do, the more it will lag.  Do not add the intervals, re-calibrate with the clock.

Comment: Maybe run the clock in another thread and have each thread do a compare on its own for multiple alarms